# How to Delete document and sub documents referenced from others collections - MongoDB Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have this collection **Cart** (*cart schema*) to delete and it is referenced with 2 other schemes, *Meal* and *Customer* (owner user, its schema is: User Schema).

How can I delete the cart by passing as req.params.id the user's id from the HTTP request?

> Cart Schema

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const idValidator = require('mongoose-id-validator');

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
 

const cartItemSchema = new Schema ({
    quantity: { type: Number, required: true },
    itemId: { type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId, required: true, ref: 'Meal' }
});

const cartSchema = new Schema ({
    cartItems : [
        cartItemSchema
    ], 
    customer: { type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId, required: true, ref: 'User'}
});


cartSchema.plugin(idValidator);
module.exports = mongoose.model('Cart', cartSchema);
```

> I created a function to delete the document, but it doesn't work, it returns the message: 'Deleted cart.', but isn't true, the document remains in collection.

```
const deleteCartByUserId = async (req, res, next) => {
    const userId = req.params.uid;

    let cart;

    try {
        cart = await Cart.find({ customer: userId });
    } catch(err) {
        const error = new HttpError('Something went wrong, could not delete cart.', 500);
        return next(error);
    }

    if(!cart) {
        const error = new HttpError('Could not find cart for this user id.', 404);
        return next(error); 
    }

    try {
        Cart.deleteOne({ customer: userId });
    } catch(err) {
        console.log(err);
        const error = new HttpError('Something went wrong, could not delete cart.', 500);
        return next(error);
    }

    res.status(200).json({ message: 'Deleted cart.' });
};
```

Comment: you can delete the cart by using cart._id and Model.findByIdAndRemove()
But each user can have multiple carts. How do you know which one you want to delete?

Comment: @Parham.rm Because every customer has one and only one cart. The user's id is passed by the client and the server deletes that specific cart. I know I need to add constraints for the cart to be unique per User, but I need to add this feature first

Comment: Ok. So I'm guessing you've forgot to use await before Cart.deleteOne.

Comment: You're right, it works now. An hour and a half without realizing this trivial mistake. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the porblem was that you missed an await before delete one function call.
Also I've changed some of youre code to make it cleaner:

```
const functionHandler = fn =>
    (req, res, next) =>
        Promise
            .resolve(fn(req, res, next))
            .catch(next);

const deleteCartByUserId = functionHandler(async (req, res) => {
    const { params: { uid: userId } } = req;
    const cart = await Cart.findOneAndDelete({ customer: userId })
    if(!cart) {
        throw new HttpError('Could not find cart for this user id.', 404);
    }
    res.status(200).json({ message: 'Deleted cart.' });
});
```

In your error handler middleware you can check for error type and if it's not HttpError use internal server error.